# get_magic_quotes_gpc() returns undefined in my code

Tags: php

I just installed a new version of XAMPP and the site that used to work perfectly now no longer works, I suppose it's a PHP incompatibility, can anyone help me? tnks in adv..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:207 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 207
```

```
    \\ The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        
        array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
        array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
        array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
        array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    }
```

thanks @WiatroBosy for your help.

I think I solved the problem because the message has now changed and has diverted the error to another file..
I solved the first problem like this..(I don't know if I did it right)

```
if(  function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
```

The new error now is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class CI_Log, because the name is already in use in D:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Log.php on line 27 (line 27) class CI_Log {
```

Comment: [That function has been removed from PHP8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php). I'd say just remove the whole if block

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0 and REMOVED in 8.0.0.

Hence you should just remove this function call from the code, along with entire condition where it's used.

Read the [documentation of `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

Comment: thanks @WiatroBosy for your help.
I think I solved the problem because the message has now changed and has diverted the error to another file ..
I solved the first problem like this .. (I don't know if I did it right)

`if(  function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc())`

The new error now is:

`Fatal error: Cannot declare class CI_Log, because the name is already in use in D:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Log.php on line 27`

(line 27)

`class CI_Log {`

Comment: @DottorCox it worked for me. Good hint with function_exists() Thx!